# How to connect to ssh server in PhpStorm using many users on one hostname

Tags: phpstorm

I need to connect to server using different users. I added 2 deployment profiles with different username and the same hostname. But when I press "start ssh session", I see one of  two deployment profiles. How add other profile to servers list?

PhpStorm 8.0.2 build #ps-139.732

Comment: Your OS and IDE version exactly (including build number)? Could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124136

Comment: OS - win 8, PhpStorm 8.0.2 build #ps-139.732. 

Yes it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in PhpStorm that shows only limited number of entries in some lists -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124136

Accordingly to that ticket the issue has been fixed -- the fix will be available in PhpStorm 8.0.3 (build #139.927 or newer).